# Index Out Of Range Error When Deleting Tableview Data And Firebase Data

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete data in my Firebase database and then listen for `.childRemoved` so I can update the TableView. I originally tried to remove the object from the array using the code below but got an index out of range error in `cellForRowAt` in `indexPath.row`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child(post.postKey).removeValue()
        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid!)").child("posts").child("\(post.postKey)").removeValue()
        //print("deleted post \(deletedPost)")
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {

    }
}
```

So, I decided to try to delete the Firebase data first and then listen at `.childRemoved` with the following combination of code (I commented out the removal of array objects in the `editingStyle` code).

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        //posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        //tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child(post.postKey).removeValue()
        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid!)").child("posts").child("\(post.postKey)").removeValue()
        //print("deleted post \(deletedPost)")
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}
```

Then, I created a listener at `.childRemoved` in `ViewDidLoad` with the following.

```
 newPost.observe(.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in
        //print("CHILD REMOVED")
        //print("\(self.posts)")
        //print("\(snapshot.postKey)")
        let postId = snapshot.key
        if let indexNew = self.posts.firstIndex(where: {$0.postKey == postId}){
            self.posts.remove(at: indexNew)
            for n in 0...self.posts.count - 1 {
                print("POST \(n) - \(self.posts[n])")
            }
            print("REMOVE INDEX - \(indexNew)")
            print("POSTS AFTER REMOVAL - \(self.posts)")
            self.feedTableView.reloadData()
        }

    }, withCancel: nil)
```

I am still receiving the index out of range error at `cellForRowAt` on `indexPath.row`. Am I on the right track with the second method? If so, what am I doing wrong to cause the out of range error?

EDIT: I am adding my `cellForRowAt` where I am getting the `index out of range error` and most updated `commit editingStyle`. I'm not sure how I am running over the array since the debug statements print

```
INDEX OF POST ARRAY - 2
POSTS: SocialSpirit.Post
POSTS AFTER DELETE [SocialSpirit.Post, SocialSpirit.Post, SocialSpirit.Post]
INDEX OF POST ARRAY - 0
Fatal error: Index out of range
```

And here is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let post = posts[indexPath.row]
        DataService.ds.REF_POSTS.child(post.postKey).removeValue()
        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid!)").child("posts").child("\(post.postKey)").removeValue()
        posts.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        print("POSTS AFTER DELETE \(self.posts)")
        //print("deleted post \(deletedPost)")
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("INDEX OF POST ARRAY - \(indexPath.row)")
    print("POSTS: \(posts[indexPath.row])") //Index out of range error here
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as? PostCell{
        if let img = FeedViewController.imageCache.object(forKey: post.imageUrl as NSString) {
            cell.configureCell(post: post, img: img)
        } else {
            cell.configureCell(post: post)
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        return PostCell()
    }

}
```

Comment: When deleting, you have to iterate backward. Think about it - if you have 3 items in the list and write a loop to iterate through them, the loop would run from 0 to 2. If you delete the first item, you will run off the end because there are only 2 items now while the loop expected 3.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand generally that I am running off the end of my `posts` array. What I am confused about is how to first remove that `post` from Firebase and then the `posts` array. In which function should I iterate backward?

Comment: The array. It's the only place you can run off the end in the code you've posted.

Comment: @KenWhite Okay. I am not sure I understand exactly what to do. I added an edit that just shows `commit editingStyle` and `cellForRowAt`. I am not sure how I am getting an overrun as I am checking the array after deletion with `0..2` and then when I go into `cellForRowAt` the index is out of range at `0` even though when I checked it had 3 posts in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function this way removes the index error and correctly updates the tableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            let post = posts[indexPath.row]
            DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child("\(uid!)").child("posts").child("\(post.postKey)").removeValue()
        }

    }
```